# ViewModel instance will always be recreated when switching between pages

Tags: unity-container, prism, uwp

I'm using Prism 6, UWP with Unity.

The ViewModels will be automatically injected into the datacontext of the page. However, when I navigate between the pages the viewmodels will always be recreated. Is this behaviour desired by Prism and Unity?

Imagine the following scenario, a user enter some data into a page therefore the proper properties of the viewmodel will be set. When the user is switching back to another page and revisits the page all entered data are lost, because a new viewmodel instance is created.

At the moment my workaround is to override OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatingFrom to save all properties of the viewmodel with the SessionStateService manual. I'm not sure if this is the correct way?

You can reproduce this behaviour with the following example:
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Windows/tree/master/SplitViewSample/SplitViewSample

Comment: I'm not familiar with Prism 6 so I don't know how it's plugged in, but I know Unity has a way to control the lifetime of the instances. Use it to set your viewmodel as singleton, so it won't be recreated every time

Comment: Please show some code, how you register your views with unity and the constructors of your views

Comment: I added a url to the officiall prism example, which also got the same behaviour I descriped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be solved when you register your ViewModels as singletons (`ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`) in the UnityContainer. The best place for this would be the `App.xaml.cs` in method `OnInitializeAsync`

```
protected override Task OnInitializeAsync(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    Container.RegisterType<MyViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

    // rest of the method
}
```

Comment: Your solution works. I tried to adopt it the following way:
 ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver((viewType) => {
  [...]
                if (Container.Registrations.Count(a => a.Name == type.Name) == 0)
                {
                    Container.RegisterInstance(type.Name, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
                }
                return type;}); Although the viewmodels got registered in the UnityContainer the viewmodels will not be reused. Any ideas?

Comment: @Briefkasten `Container.RegisterInstance(type.Name, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())` this is wrong. This will register a ContainerControlledLifetimeManager with the given name.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using Prism, I'm using modified version of Template 10.
I just had a quick look at the Prism source code. Looks like Template 10 borrowed a lot of ideas from Prism.

I'll try to answer your question from 2 perspectives:

1) AFAIK, in Prism there is a static class with which you can set how to create/resolve you view model when it is automatically looked up for the corresponding View. The class is `ViewModelLocationProvider`, in file [ViewModelLocationProvider.cs](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/7b79712a0008274f14e8c8f3b2072e7ae25556e6/Source/Prism/Mvvm/ViewModelLocationProvider.cs) you can use following methods to setup the 'view model factories'

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the default view model factory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="viewModelFactory">The view model factory which provides the ViewModel type as a parameter.</param>
    public static void SetDefaultViewModelFactory(Func<Type, object> viewModelFactory)
    {
        _defaultViewModelFactory = viewModelFactory;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the default view model factory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="viewModelFactory">The view model factory that provides the View instance and ViewModel type as parameters.</param>
    public static void SetDefaultViewModelFactory(Func<object, Type, object> viewModelFactory)
    {
        _defaultViewModelFactoryWithViewParameter = viewModelFactory;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the view model factory for the specified view type name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="viewTypeName">The name of the view type.</param>
    /// <param name="factory">The viewmodel factory.</param>
    public static void Register(string viewTypeName, Func<object> factory)
    {
        _factories[viewTypeName] = factory;
    }
```

then all the logic for getting view model instance is in the following, pay attention to the comment summary here, it describes the logic/strategy

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Automatically looks up the viewmodel that corresponds to the current view, using two strategies:
    /// It first looks to see if there is a mapping registered for that view, if not it will fallback to the convention based approach.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="view">The dependency object, typically a view.</param>
    /// <param name="setDataContextCallback">The call back to use to create the binding between the View and ViewModel</param>
    public static void AutoWireViewModelChanged(object view, Action<object, object> setDataContextCallback)
    {
        // Try mappings first
        object viewModel = GetViewModelForView(view);

        // Fallback to convention based
        if (viewModel == null)
        {
            var viewModelType = _defaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver(view.GetType());
            if (viewModelType == null) 
                return;

            viewModel = _defaultViewModelFactoryWithViewParameter != null ? _defaultViewModelFactoryWithViewParameter(view, viewModelType) : _defaultViewModelFactory(viewModelType);
        }

        setDataContextCallback(view, viewModel);
    }
```

on line 87 and 96 you get you view model instance for the corresponding view.

So that means, if you don't call any of those methods to setup the factories, it will fall back to the default factory which is

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The default view model factory whic provides the ViewModel type as a parameter.
    /// </summary>
    static Func<Type, object> _defaultViewModelFactory = type => Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

that is pretty clear you will always get a new instance.

Regarding Unity, I didn't see anything special, the only clue is that in the `PrismApplication` class in [PrismApplication.cs](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/ff93f11245bbde7b44755e2abb40c8c177bdc3a5/Source/Windows10/Prism.Windows/PrismApplication.cs), it sets up the factory like following:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Configures the <see cref="ViewModelLocator"/> used by Prism.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
    {
        ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory((type) => Resolve(type));
    }
```

that means the factory is now using

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Resolves the specified type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The type.</param>
    /// <returns>A concrete instance of the specified type.</returns>
    protected virtual object Resolve(Type type)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
```

which you can override with your own implementation.

In `PrismUnityApplication` class, [PrismUnityApplication.cs](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/ff93f11245bbde7b44755e2abb40c8c177bdc3a5/Source/Windows10/Prism.Unity.Windows/PrismUnityApplication.cs), it offers a default implementation to resolve the instance with Unity

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Implements the Resolves method to be handled by the Unity Container.
    /// Use the container to resolve types (e.g. ViewModels and Flyouts)
    /// so their dependencies get injected
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The type.</param>
    /// <returns>A concrete instance of the specified type.</returns>
    protected override object Resolve(Type type)
    {
        return Container.Resolve(type);
    }
```

and yeah, like other guys mentioned, you can control the lifetime of your view models yourself via Unity.

2) sorry for the long answer, 
but I feel it's better to show you some code that will make things clear. 
I'll keep the 2nd one short.

In my opinion, you don't need a view model when your view is gone. 
I am not sure how the Frame stack is implemented in UWP and how they manage the view/page instances. I would assume once you navigate to a different page, the previous view/page should be released or can be released at GC, and you have the parameter and page type to be able to navigate back, but it will be a new instance and you restore the state of your view by restoring your view model.

so really, i think you're on the right track. and you should save/persist your user data whenever you can, and your solution works when the app is suspended and then is resumed, you can still recover the state of your view.

Thanks for reading.